# How do I get my CSS to stop resetting?

Tags: theming

I am working on a site that I inherited from someone else (i.e. I didn't design the theme). I've made a bunch of changes in the CSS to make the site look better, and everything seems fine, but after a couple days, the CSS resets to the old CSS. I then clear the cache and my changes reappear. I have to clear the cache every few days to get my changes to stay. I don't understand what could be causing this. I believe the theme is a ZURB Foundation subtheme.